# Selenium. Проблема с нажатием на радио-кнопку и обычную кнопку

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Всем привет, это опять я с вопросом насчет selenium. У меня выводит ошибку, хотя вроде все отлично должно работать, помогите, пожалуйста.
Весь код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome.get("https://bigjpg.com/")
# assert 'Bigjpg - Средство увеличения / увеличения масштабирования без увеличения изображения AI с высоким разрешением с использованием глубоких сверточных нейронных сетей' in chrome.title
fileInput = chrome.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type=file]')
filePath = r"C:\Users\user\Videos\Little_Women_1\Little_Women_1_000001.jpg"
fileInput.send_keys(filePath)
# click on start button
chrome.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary.big_begin').click()
# click on radio-button - 4x
chrome.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="radio"][name="x2"][value="2"]').click()
# click on radio-button - last noise element
chrome.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="radio"][name="noise"][value="3"]').click()
chrome.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#big_ok.btn.btn-primary').click()
assert "No results found." not in chrome.page_source
chrome.quit()
```

Часть кода, в которой может быть ошибка:

```
# click on radio-button - 4x
chrome.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="radio"][name="x2"][value="2"]').click()
# click on radio-button - last noise element
chrome.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="radio"][name="noise"][value="3"]').click()
chrome.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#big_ok.btn.btn-primary').click()
```

Сама ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    chrome.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="radio"][name="x2"][value="2"]').click()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\for_work_with_website\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 93, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\for_work_with_website\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 403, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\for_work_with_website\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\for_work_with_website\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.107)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x0032ACD3+2075859]
    Ordinal0 [0x002BEE61+1633889]
    Ordinal0 [0x001BB680+571008]
    Ordinal0 [0x001EBBD6+768982]
    Ordinal0 [0x001E1C76+728182]
    Ordinal0 [0x0020731C+881436]
    Ordinal0 [0x001E15BF+726463]
    Ordinal0 [0x00207534+881972]
    Ordinal0 [0x0021B56A+963946]
    Ordinal0 [0x00207136+880950]
    Ordinal0 [0x001DFEFD+720637]
    Ordinal0 [0x001E0F3F+724799]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x005DEED2+2769538]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x005D0D95+2711877]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x003BA03A+521194]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x003B8DA0+516432]
    Ordinal0 [0x002C682C+1665068]
    Ordinal0 [0x002CB128+1683752]
    Ordinal0 [0x002CB215+1683989]
    Ordinal0 [0x002D6484+1729668]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75F0343D+18]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x773A9812+99]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x773A97E5+54]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить задержку перед кликом на радио "[name="x2"]", при нажатии на big_begin появляется всплывающее окно с анимацией, нужно дождаться, пока анимация завершится

Comment: @check - `radio_button_4x = WebDriverWait(chrome, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="radio"][name="x2"][value="2"]')))
radio_button_4x.click()` - вот, я исправил, но он всё равно, не дожидаясь истечения таймера, нажимает и выводит ошибку

Comment: Я использовал `time.sleep(1)` между каждым нажатием на радио-кнопку и код заработал

Comment: Вы импортировали `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`, но нигде ее в коде не прописали. За использование time.sleep() обычно ругают) Старайтесь максимально избавляться от слипов в проекте. Для этого у Вас импортирован `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`